# How to properly wrap routes in react-router v5?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The problem when I open `"/view"` route entire `BaseLayout` is rendering and I've tried many different ways with no luck.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Root>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <BaseLayout>
          <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/sa" exact component={sample} />
        </BaseLayout>
        <Route path="/view" exact component={Post} />
      </Root>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try to wrap your `Routes` using [`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch).

Comment: tried it still the problem exists

Comment: Please post some sample URLs and the associated components to render. The code snippet provided indicates what was tried, but not the desired outcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `render` props instead of the `component` one and if you wrap the component you want to render using your `BaseLayout` like the above, it should work:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
                <Root>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/dashboard" exact render={() => (
                      <BaseLayout><Dashboard /></BaseLayout>
                    )} />
                    <Route path="/sa" exact render={() => (
                      <BaseLayout><sample /></BaseLayout>
                    )} />
                    <Route path="/view" exact component={Post} />
                </Root>
        </Router>
      );

    }
```

Comment: It worked but one problem how to add not found the route I've tried to add at the bottom but again not found rendering every route

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly. Please create a codesandbox so it will be easier to help you out.

Comment: You don't need to add the `render` attribute. `<Route>` allows to simply use children and [official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route) even recommends it: *The recommended method of rendering something with a <Route> is to use children elements, as shown above.*